# Should classes define getters for their dependencies?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Let's say I have a class car which has a motor.

The class motor is defined like this:

```
class Motor {
    private String code;
    
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

How should the class car be defined, assuming we need to access the motor's code from whoever has access to the car?

```
class Car {
    private Motor motor;

    public Motor getMotor() {
        return motor;
    }
}
```

Which allows for this:

```
Car car = ...
Motor motor = car.getMotor();
String code = motor.getCode();
```

Or

```
class Car {
    private Motor motor;

    public String getMotorCode() {
        return motor.getCode();
    }
}
```

Which allows for this:

```
Car car = ...
String code = car.getMotorCode();
```

I assume the second option is best since it follows the Law of Demeter, which the first one doesn't. On the other hand, should the outer class define every single getter from the inner class(es)? Should the motor ever be exposed with a `getMotor()`?

Comment: This is a very good software design question, but it is absolutelly opinion-based. Every developer and architect out there will have a different opinion, always based on their experience. And they all will claim to be impartial, pattern-based, etc but, at the end, it's only a matter of taste and preferences

Comment: It depends on the interface you want to expose to your clients. If they should expect to get a motor code directly from a car instance, then go with the 2nd approach; don't force them to dig into the inners of `Car` to access what they need. This is the idea behind the law of demeter: Expose the interface your clients need, don't have them digging into internals for it. If they access something mutable, they now how the power to change the state of the car indirectly via the motor, something they probably shouldn't be able to do.

Comment: @fps it's not a matter of *taste*. It depends entirely on the actual situation. The example is a purely hypothetical and naive situation, but my answer is basically the same in a real world setting based on my experience. These "theory first" programmers seem to be so high strung before they get a few years of real world experience and understand that theory and practice are two different things (somewhat unfortunately). Law of Demeter is not a law, and following it blindly doesn't make you a good developer, it makes you a fool for following things blindly.

Comment: Maybe that's the curse of programming, you generally deal with deterministic things, logical decisions and so on, but still in many cases there's no correct answer and the best you can do is "well, it depends". That's why the AI-robots will never overthrow the common programmer. Fight the power!

Comment: @Kayaman I know what you mean. But even among experienced developers and architects, there's no consensus. There are different opinions, based on alleged experience and also on personal taste. I've seen this *taste* thing many times, I have experience on that :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since `Motor` is going to be used by itself without its enclosing `Car` if it warrants its own class. If it doesn't, then the `Car` class can store `String motorCode` in itself. This assumes that `Car` is a composite model without significant logic, as it seems to be in the example.

It's the anorectic class design of the example that makes it unclear, but in a real world application the `Motor` class has dozens of fields and composite classes of its own. The `Car` class can't have methods for all of them.

The `Car` class may then have methods that aggregate data from different composite fields, or make some often used data easier to access without long `car.getMotor().getSomething().getData()` chains.

Having this same vehicle-motor-etc. hierarchy in our product (although much fuller), I know that in real world applications `Motor` will be handled separately. As well as potentially things like `Transmission`, `Tyres` and so on. So the end result is a hybrid approach where you provide access to the internal composite elements, since sometimes you need it. The object graph is too big and not interesting enough to warrant a lot of design, so it's a trade-off between encapsulation and development speed.

Comment: I can't disagree with any of this but, in the end, it's going to come down to a matter of preference, and an intuition about which approach offers the most expressive power. I suspect it's something that every experienced developer will have an opinion on, and there won't be any consensus. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Chiming in to say that I agree with Kevin. You'll never get a perfect consensus on this but as for me, I tend to focus on object ownership and how you'd go about providing a human interface. If there's a controller, then the controller is the interface. In the case of a car, if getting information about the car is the desired outcome, I'd reference OBD. I'd probably create an OBD controller class which would then getEngine() or getFaultCodes(). Each individual part on the car might have its own set of pvt characteristics. So the engine might have a numCylinders, a bore, an oilLevel, etc.

Comment: I'm not looking for consensus. I'm telling you I've written a vehicle hierarchy like that in our product, and it's cumbersome to handle. I'm not looking for opinions, I have experience.

Comment: What about content coupling? If `Motor` is mutable, exposing it like that could lead to debugging nightmares.

Comment: @Dioxin then don't make `Motor` mutable.

Comment: @Kayaman -- we _all_ have experience. That's why there will be no consensus.

Comment: @Kayaman If you're not looking for opinions, why did you ask a question about design practices? ;)

Comment: @TheFunk I didn't ask this question. I answered it because I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

`car.getMotor().getCode()` wins.

Why?

- It’s less code; you don’t have to implement `getMotorCode()`
- `getMotorCode()` breaks Demeter's Law – a car would know about, and be coupled to, what fields a motor has. What if one day there’s a motor that doesn’t have a code?
- `getMotorCode()` is a convenience method that adds little value
- `getMotorCode()` is not where a coder would expect to find a car’s motor’s code, but `car.getMotor().getCode()` is
- `getMotorCode()` is not industry standard - off hand I cannot recall seeing such a method as `getMotorCode()` (and I’ve seen a *lot* of code)

Regarding breaking the Law of Demeter, quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter):

> An object a can request a service (call a method) of an object instance b, but object a should not "reach through" object b to access yet another object, c, to request its services. Doing so would mean that object a implicitly requires greater knowledge of object b's internal structure.

This precisely describes what `getMotorCode()` does.

Answer (score 0):

I see this as rather simple: is `Motor` *mutable* or is `Motor` having some information that should be hidden (i.e. : not exposed to clients/callers)? If any of the answer is *yes* - simply don't expose `Motor` directly, but only via the information that is allowed.

Otherwise you risk:

- for callers to change the internals of `Motor` (which you might not want)
- exposing too much (like may be `VIN` should not be visible for everyone)

Answer (score 0):

@Bohemian♦ got this right.
Getter and Setters in Java are used to provide standard ways to return data.
Implement `Motor` this way :

```java
public String getCode() {
    return "Code: " + code;
}
```

Does your `Car` class needs to know how to return a code ? **No**
Let's imagine you implement `getMotorCode()` in `Car`, will you duplicate how to return a code ?  **No**
You change the way to return a code like `return "C: " + code;`, will you change every method like `getMotorCode()` you've implemented ? **No**

`car.getMotor().getCode()` is the standard because each part manages its job.

Answer (score 0):

I think most answers so far didn't mention the most important aspect: your classes should always strive to provide *services*, not *objects*.

Whenever you have a getter that returns objects, you make the first step towards breaking "tell, don't ask".

Tell your client code to do something (by invoking services of other objects) instead of forcing the client to retrieve other objects, to then make decisions based on the state of such objects!